# Bootstrap 4 theme colors: variables vs map

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4 it is possible to change the theme colors by overriding the variables like this:

```
$primary: #0074d9;
$danger: #ff4136;
```

Or by modifying the theme-colors map like this:

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #0074d9,
  "danger": #ff4136
);
```

When and why should we use one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact, it should be better to always override your theme colors in the `$theme-colors` map to ensure replacing the colors from where bootstrap will use those colors later when generating the corresponding CSS. [Bootstrap encourages to do so.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#maps-and-loops)

If you decide to override the default color definition, you will be overriding the creation of the colormap itself, so bootstrap won't have access to default colors anymore.

You could do the following:

**Option 1**

Override the default values (not encouraged by Bootstrap).

**Option 2**

Override the map, using hex values:

```
$theme-colors : (
    'primary' : #0074d9,
    'danger'  : #ff4136
);
```

Then you could access any of your theme colors by using `map_get`:

```
$my-color : map_get($theme-colors, 'primary'); // #0074d9
```

**Option 3**

You could define your own set of variables to override the map, then you'll always have access to your variables without using `map_get`:

```
$my-primary-color : #0074d9;
$my-danger-color  : #ff4136;

$theme-colors : (
    'primary' : $my-primary-color,
    'danger'  : $my-danger-color
);
```

Comment: The thing with overriding the map instead of the variables is that then we don't have access to the variables of the new colors in our own sass files.

Comment: You could then define your own set of variables, and use those variables to override the map; that way you'll have access to your own variables and you'll change the theme according to what Boostrap docs encourage you to do. You can always use `map_get` to get the value. For example if you override the `primary` value from the map, you could use `map_get($theme_colors, 'primary');` to get its value.

Comment: @slacle i've updated my answer to better fit your needs. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: here can we override the border-color as well ?

Comment: @VishalTanna from which mixin? The border color applied where in the scss files? To the buttons?

Comment: @muesca yes inside scss file as we overide button color in above we have override the border color

Comment: @VishalTanna maybe just specify the color you want, if the background color that you setted overrides the whole button, create a selector to specify the desired border color. That should do the trick. Maybe you can post a question about it.

Comment: For others using bootstrap 5 - `$primary: [color]` is the preferred method: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/#maps-and-loops